# Get com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException when reading strings with spaces

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore to store my data. When I try to read data with a space in the string I get the following error message:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 79
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)
    at POS.Firebase.readCounts(Firebase.java:47)
    at POS.Main.main(Main.java:52)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 79
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1298)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInObject(JsonReader.java:722)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:382)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:349)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:169)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
    ... 13 more
```

code for getting the data from firebase is

```
for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : collection.get().get().getDocuments()) {
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.getData())));
            reader.setLenient(true);
            Item item = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Item.class);
            Arrays.itemArrayList.add(item);
        }
```

Is there a way to store the data without adding quotation marks when i enter the data
[Data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDzOP.png)

Comment: Firestore doesn't store data as JSON.  DocumentSnapshot data isn't JSON either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error **not** because you are using a "space" in a String but because you are using `JSON`. As Doug Stevenson commented, Firestore doesn't store data as JSON. You should get the data according to the data type that is stored.

According to the [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) documentation, you have many options in which you can get the data. You can even get the data according to custom data type using [toObject(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) method.

> Returns the contents of the document converted to a POJO or null if the document doesn't exist.

Note, you can add in Firestore a "space" or even an empty String as a value of a property which is of type String. Both operations are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

return type of documentSnapshot.getData() is Map. To convert Map to json Object Just pass the value to JSONObect constructor like below

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
```

now the problem you will face is Map's key is string but value is Object which will print some random value in your JSONObject.

So the best approach is to iterate your map, get values and create an object from it.